# iOS constraints - can't figure out how

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, xcode8

So I can't figure out how to get my page to look the same on all devices (for example on an iphone 5&7).

This is my cell.xib:

[image]

The last one on the lower right is a label.

This is how it looks on the iphone 7 (this is how it should look):

[image]

and this is the iphone 5:

[image]

and yes I realize it seems easy, at least I feel like it seems easy, but having spent HOURS on trying all sorts of constraints combinations I'm worn out. Could someone guide me? Like litereally guide me? step by step.

Comment: Is your app supports iOS9+ ?
If so, you can use UIStackView to place the coffee beans inside, it will adjust the image sizes in order for them to fit the space between the big image and the screen trailing

Comment: all I'm seeing is horizontal stack view and vertical stack view?

Comment: You need Horizontal Stack View.
Then make sure to set the constraints for the big image trailing to the xib trailing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be to put all your image views some stack views.

Each row of 5 would be a horizontal stack view with 5 image views in it.
Those two horizontal stack views would then be placed in a vertical stack view.

This would have leading space to the large image view and trailing space to the label, which would in turn have trailing space to the view's trailing anchor.

You should then be able to configure the stack views to keep their content's at a 1:1 aspect ratio.

Comment: I'll give this a go

Comment: can't get it to work. Each horizontal stack keeps changing size when I try to put the same constraints for the 2 of them...

Comment: If you embed each of them in a vertical stack view, you shouldn't need to give them constraints. You should only need to constrain the stack view they are in.

Comment: So here's what I do, add vertical view. Add 2 horizontal views. Then I add my imageviews into the 2 horizontal views and add the constraints for the vertical view. Then it says it needs all constraints for the imageviews

Comment: Any chance you could provide a screenshot showing which constraints you've set on the vertical stack view?

Comment: In the end this solution worked, I must admit I am unsure how as when I added the vertical view, if I added a trailing constraint to the label it would freak out and suddenly have a giant width. In the end I got the label to work but I'm not sure how. 

I have a feeling the cell I have doesn't change size for the different devices which is why I sometimes would see my label and sometimes not. But I'm not sure how to make it so the cell itself changes size for each device.